# Why does python only shows the first half of the list in tkinter?

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I tried to write a program, which shows a list of integers in a table in a new tkinter window by pressing a button. Than I run it, only the first half of the list was showed, but no errors was indicated. I tried to double the body of the for-loop, but one at uneven number of integers of the list and two at a even were missing. Here is the isolated problem:

```
from tkinter import * 

def table():
   filewin = Toplevel(root)
   x = 1
   numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

   for i in numbers:
       Label(filewin, text = ("Value", x, ":")).grid(column = 0, row = i)
       Label(filewin, text = (liste.pop(0),"cm")).grid(column = 1, row = i)
       x += 1


root = Tk()

Button(root, text = 'show list', command = table).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`liste.pop(0)` removes the first value of the list. You probably don't want to do that. I think that you should use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
def table():
   filewin = Toplevel(root)
   numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

   for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
       Label(filewin, text = ("Value", i + 1, ":")).grid(column = 0, row = i)
       Label(filewin, text = (n, "cm")).grid(column = 1, row = i)
```

Comment: Where you have `(x, "cm")` you should have `(n, "cm")`

Comment: @KJTHoward Now I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you pop off one of the numbers the list that `i` is iterating through gets shorter, that's why it terminates early. Also instead of using `x` as a separate variable to keep track of the iterations, you can use `enumerate`. Doing this, and not popping off the number, just displaying it, fixes your issue:

```
from tkinter import * 

def table():
   filewin = Toplevel(root)

   numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

   for i,number in enumerate(numbers):
       Label(filewin, text = ("Value", i+1, ":")).grid(column = 0, row = i)
       Label(filewin, text = (number,"cm")).grid(column = 1, row = i)



root = Tk()

Button(root, text = 'show list', command = table).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I created `liste` as an independant copy of `numbers`. If you used the same list, you would have only half the list printed since you `pop` one element out of the list at each iteration.

```
from tkinter import * 

def table():
    filewin = Toplevel(root)
    x = 1
    numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
    liste = numbers.copy()
    for i in numbers:
        Label(filewin, text = ("Value", x, ":")).grid(column = 0, row = i)
        Label(filewin, text = (liste.pop(0),"cm")).grid(column = 1, row = i)
        x += 1

root = Tk()

Button(root, text = 'show list', command = table).pack()

root.mainloop()
```